# Flex - Virtual delete button

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to put a virtual delete button in flex application. I want the button to be bound to the delete key on the keyboard.

This is what i've got:

```
<s:Image id="btnDelete" x="0" y="0" width="32" height="32" source="image/delete.png" useHandCursor="true" click="deleteButtonClick(event)"/>
```

I figured out that the keycode of the delete key is 46, but can't find a way to use that in a function. I've spent a lot of time searching for an answer.

Is it even possible to do this in flex, or do I have to use action script?

Comment: I do not understand what a virtual delete button is; nor do I understand what "I want the button to be bound to the delete key on the keyboard" means.  When the user clicks your btnDelete do you want to dispatch a Keyboard event as if the delete button had been pressed?

Comment: I'm sorry. It's all a bit unclear. I wanted a button, on screen, to act as the delete button. To have the same function.

Comment: The delete button can do different things; depending on what has focus and how the application has implemented it.  You'll have to define what the delete button does before we can help. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to listen for keyboard events and not for mouse events. What you did in there is to listen for the MouseEvent.CLICK event on the image and this is not how it should work.

My suggestion is that you should listen for keyboard events on stage, and then check if the delete key was hit.

Also check adobe documentation on this 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html#includeExamplesSummary

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_11.html

See this sample

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class KeyboardEventExample extends Sprite {
        private var child:Sprite = new Sprite();
        private var bgColor:uint = 0x00CCFF;
        private var size:uint = 80;

        public function KeyboardEventExample() {
            child.graphics.beginFill(bgColor);
            child.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, size, size);
            child.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(child);
            child.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
            child.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
            child.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);

        }

        private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            stage.focus = child;
        }

        private function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
            trace("keyDownHandler: " + event.keyCode);
            trace("ctrlKey: " + event.ctrlKey);
            trace("keyLocation: " + event.keyLocation);
            trace("shiftKey: " + event.shiftKey);
            trace("altKey: " + event.altKey);

        }

        private function keyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
            trace("keyUpHandler: " + event.keyCode);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: So, i basically assign a keyboard event to the image? I'm very new at this. I'll check out the documentation. Thank you. :)

Comment: you have to listen for the event on the stage. not on the image